# request.security_lower_tf's problem with In 'array.get()'function. Index 0 is out of bounds, array size is 0

Tags: pine-script

```
res_9h = "15"
[macdLine_9h_ori, signalLine_9h_ori, histogram_9h_ori] = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, res_9h, ta.macd(close, fastLength, slowLength, signalLength))
float macdLine_9h = macdLine_9h_ori.size() > 0 ? macdLine_9h_ori.first() : na
```

i googled and told me to use `request.security_lower_tf` to avoid future data.but `request.security_lower_tf` lead to new problem,how the number of array of `request.security_lower_tf` can be 0?
the error make me cant use the The Bar Magnifier to deep backtest.
i want to fix `request.security_lower_tf`'s error or find a better way to use low frame data.

Comment: On what timeframe and tickerid are you testing this? I don't get any errors.